# There is a problem with Oracle ORA-00917: missing comma (pandas python

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I am trying to put pandas table like this into my Oracle Database.
My pandas table looks like this

[image]

this is my script to insert the data

```
INSERT INTO DATA 
(NO_TRANSMITTER,ZONA,STATUS_PELABUHAN,TO_DATE(REPORTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),STATUS)
VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)
```

It gets result like this

```
There is a problem with Oracle ORA-00917: missing comma
```

I don't know where comma needed to. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's a typo that you cannot use a formatted expression(`TO_DATE(REPORTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`) as a column list component. Presumably use `REPORTDATE` only instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `TO_DATE` into the `VALUES` clause and not into the column identifier list:

```sql
INSERT INTO DATA (
  NO_TRANSMITTER,
  ZONA,
  STATUS_PELABUHAN,
  REPORTDATE,
  STATUS
) VALUES (
  :1,
  :2,
  TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
  :4,
  :5
)
```

Or, if the value in Pandas, is already stored as a `datetime` (and not a string) then simplify it to:

```sql
INSERT INTO DATA (
  NO_TRANSMITTER,
  ZONA,
  STATUS_PELABUHAN,
  REPORTDATE,
  STATUS
) VALUES (
  :1,
  :2,
  :3,
  :4,
  :5
)
```

Comment: I tried the first tips but it get error like this:
There is a problem with Oracle ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format

Comment: @RidwanNurzeha Then your string does not (always) match the format model `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`.